# Writing out the log likelihood for a mixed effects model with multiple variance components

Tags: mixed-model, likelihood

For a given model:

$y_{ik} = \mu_k + \beta X + u_k X + b_i + \epsilon_{ik}$

where $u \sim N(0, \sigma_{u}^{2} I)$,  $b \sim N(0, \sigma_{b}^2 I)$ and $\epsilon \sim N(0,\sigma_{e}^2 I)$.

Assuming the $\epsilon_i$ are normally distributed, I am trying to write out the log likelihood for the above equation. However, given that there are multiple variance components in the equation, how do I go about doing this? Here's what I have so far.

$l(Y; X, \beta, \sigma_{u}, \sigma_{b}, \sigma_{e}) = - \frac{n}{2} log(2\pi + V^2) - \frac{1}{2V^2} \sum_{i=1}^{n} (y_{ik} - \mu_k - \beta X - u_k X - b_i)^2$

where --

$V = \sigma_u^2 + \sigma_b^2 + \sigma_e^2$

Comment: The model as you've written it would not be identified. If $y_{ik}$ is something like the subject $i$ in group $k$ observation then you would need repeated measurements on each subject for $\sigma^{2}_{b}$ to be distinguishable from $\sigma^{2}_{\epsilon}$. Maybe there is a $t$ subscript missing from $\epsilon_{ik}$?